# Having trouble rendering pug extend/block?

Tags: pug

The block content header is not showing up on my html page. I have looked through a few tutorials and other stackoverflow articles near as I can tell I am following the correct syntax. I am sure I am missing something but I cannot find it. Please help if you can.

I left a comment in the code. I tried changing the position of the block as well the indent of the code as well. I also tried adding append and prepend as suggested in other articles. As well as changing header to headings to make sure I didn't have a conflict.

````
doctype html
html
body
    block header // have tried with append & prepend and tried it below h1 tag
        h1 Index Page
        p This is the index page

```header.pug:
extends index

block header
    label page1 
    label page2

I am not getting an errors with this code. It is not displaying any of the content from header.pug.
````

Answer (score 0):

I think the indent below `html` and the `block header` is not correct. And by the way `head` is missing.

index.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body

    include header

    block content
```

header.pug

```
label page1 
label page2
```

content.pug

```
extends index.pug
  h1 Index Page
  p This is the index page
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice unfortunately it is still not working. I can't help feeling like I'm missing something like the indents but just can't figure it out. I also tried in both chrome and firefox to be sure and removed the .pug since it shouldn't be necessary. If you have any more advice don't hesitate to respond.

Comment: Please see my update. I added a `content.pug` example to demonstrate when to use `include` and when to use `extends`. So you see the header is just included by the index file. To include `header` put in the right path e.g.  `include ../partials/header` or just `include ./header`.

Comment: Thanks again for your response I appreciate your help. I got the include to work, but still can't get the block working. I'll keep plugging at it though. You've been very helpful.

Comment: @LeoKnox Which page are you viewing? Note that this approach won't put the contents of `content.pug` on the "index" page. It will create a separate "content" page (likely visitable at `content.html`, but that depends on your setup).

Comment: @LeoKnox You should create a `wrapper.pug` that includes your doctype, head, etc. and then an `index.pug` that extends the wrapper and includes your `h1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing how extends work. The file that contains the `extends` declaration is what becomes the page, and it just uses the markup from the other file it extends.

I've modified @kmgt's answer to illustrate this principle. Note the different names for each file.

**wrapper.pug**

```
doctype html
html
  head
  body

    include header

    block content
```

**header.pug**

```
label page1 
label page2
```

**index.pug**

```
extends wrapper

append content
  h1 Index Page
  p This is the index page
```

**about.pug**

```
extends wrapper

append content
  h1 About Page
  p This is the about page
```